# Error trying to get tmux 1.6 installed - E: Unable to locate package libevent

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, ubuntu-11.10

```
$ pwd 
$ /home/durrantm/Downloads/tmux-1.6

durrantm.../tmux-1.6$ ./configure && make
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
...
...
configure: error: "libevent not found"
durrantm.../tmux-1.6$ sudo apt-get install libevent
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libevent
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 bundles *tmux* 1.5. That *tmux* package [requires the `libevent-2.0-5` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/tmux) to satisfy its runtime requirement. The corresponding [build requirement is `libevent-dev`](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tmux/tmux_1.5-1.dsc).

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```